# Should we never have a collider component on a game object unless we also have rigidbody?

Tags: unity-game-engine

After watching [this](https://youtu.be/XtR29MmzuT0?t=792) (from 13:12 to the end) official Unity tutorial I have a question: Does this mean that ideally we should never have a collider component on a game object unless we also have rigidbody? Because if we only have a collider, Unity will consider the game object as static. So we should always add rigidbody and indicate that it is Kinematic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to use colliders on static objects that don't move **without adding the rigidbody**. It is even better for performance as these colliders are cached in the physics engine.

There is no point in adding a Rigidbody to lets say a floor, that will never move.

Comment: Did you watch the video? If I understood the video correctly, Unity says pretty much the opposite to what you just commented.

Comment: Yes, I watched it. The way I understood it is Unity will recalculate all static colliders if any of them move. If you are not moving these static colliders there are no recalculations done. Thats why you have to add a RigidBody to any collider that moves to change it from static do dynamic. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I just re-watched the part where he talks about the static and dynamic objects a few more times and I think you're right. I totally misunderstood the video. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Static colliders don't automatically get recalculated at runtime if any of them move.